# How to open menu in the split view from code?

Tags: onsen-ui

The sliding menu template has a button on the toolbar that opens the side menu (shows it). The same menu (I mean appearance) is used in the split view example app. In this case there is no menu button on the toolbar, but the menu, even in the portait view, can be open by swiping right. Why not allow a user to open the menu from a button? Unfortunately there's no toggleMenu() method for the  object. There is however openMenu() method but it doesn't work if used from code. My example code is:

```
<ons-split-view
    secondary-page="secondary.html"
    main-page="page1.html"
    main-page-width="70%"
    collapse="portrait"
    var="menu">
  </ons-split-view>

  <script type="text/ons-template" id="page1.html">
    <ons-page class="center">

      <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.openMenu()">
            <ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
      </ons-toolbar>

    </ons-page>
  </script>
```

Could you please me to achieve the effect of opening the menu by clicking on a button?

Raf

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found it... `ons.splitView.toggle()` - it opens/closes the menu.